# start a websocket server in php from the first client request

Tags: php, websocket

I am trying to use websocket for replacing constants ajax request to the server, that updates ajax information.

As far as I know in the client-server scenario I should launch a php websocket server from command line:

```
php -q myserver.php
```

WHat I am trying to obtain is to lauch the server when I client connects for the first time, and use this server for all the other clients, **without using the command line**:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:10000/myserver.php");
```

This command I want to run the server if it is not running and open a connection for this client.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible but you should look at [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)

```
var host = "ws://localhost:10000/myserver.php";
try{
  socket = new WebSocket(host);
  log('WebSocket - status '+socket.readyState);
  socket.onopen    = function(msg){ log("Welcome - status "+this.readyState); };
  socket.onmessage = function(msg){ log("Received: "+msg.data); };
  socket.onclose   = function(msg){ log("Disconnected - status "+this.readyState); };
}
catch(ex){ log(ex); }
```

Server Side that you run `php -q myserver.php`

```
log("Handshaking...");
list($resource,$host,$origin) = getheaders($buffer);
$upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Origin: " . $origin . "\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Location: ws://" . $host . $resource . "\r\n" .
        "\r\n";
$handshake = true;
socket_write($socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0)));
```

phpwebsocket does not support `RFC-6455` by default so you can also look at the following

- https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets
- https://github.com/sebcode/php-websocketserver
- https://github.com/Martijnc/phpwebsockets

Comment: A glance at the code suggests that phpwebsocket appears only supports the deprecated Hixie-76 variant of websockets.  This won't work with most browsers.  Am I missing support for the newer RFC6455 format?  If not, it'd probably be best not to recommend use of phpwebsocket.

Comment: I just have a look at php socket it need command line run: From the command line, run the server.php program to listen for socket connections.

Comment: @simonc that can easily be fixed using pack `pack('C2a*', 0b10000001, 0b01111111 & strlen($upgrade.chr(0)), $upgrade.chr(0));` but all the same good observation i would update my answer with other alternatives with `RFC-6455` support by default